# JsonConvert.SerializeObject followed by JsonConvert.DeserializeObject throws InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

Trying to serialise and deserialise

```
public class DatabaseResponse
{
    public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
    public string[] Tables { get; set; }
}
```

Serialise works ok

```
DatabaseResponse databaseResponse = new DatabaseResponse
{
    DatabaseName = databaseName,
    Tables = tableList.ToArray()
};
string response= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(databaseResponse);
```

but deserialise

```
DatabaseResponse databaseResponse1 = (DatabaseResponse)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
```

throws

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'DatabaseResponse'.'
```

I have looked at other solutions here but none seem to deal with classes that include both simple properties and array properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.DeserializeObject(json)` [will return an `object`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm) representing the internal classes that JSON.NET uses to represent a JSON document when it doesn't know how you want to represent it.

In your specific case, it has represented it as a `JObject`, which has no means of being directly cast to a `DatabaseResponse`. You should instead use the generic [`.DeserializeObject<T>(json)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject__1.htm), thereby explicitly telling JSON.NET what to deserialize it as:

```
DatabaseResponse databaseResponse1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DatabaseResponse>(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to cast it. It is a generic method:

```
DatabaseResponse databaseResponse1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DatabaseResponse>(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DatabaseResponse databaseResponse1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DatabaseResponse>(response);
```